# Suggest good UI framework for react-native app. I used expo to create project

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-ios

**i need some good ui components library for react-native like react material ui for react web applications**

Please suggest a library that you have used in you projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**React Native Elements**

As a cross-platform UI Toolkit, you can now use RNE on the web & share your codebase between your React Native + React web apps.

[View](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/getting_started.html)

**Nativebase**

Essential cross-platform UI components for React Native & Vue Native

[View](https://nativebase.io/)

**React Native Material UI**

Highly customizable material design components for React Native.

[View](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui)

**UI Kitten**

React Native framework for creating stunning cross-platform mobile applications. Design system based brings your product from MVP to enterprise. Forever Open Source and free.

[View](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/)

**React Native UI Lib**

[View](https://github.com/wix/react-native-ui-lib)